# Allow one gocron at a time

Tags: go

I have the following code snipped which schedules the job to be run after the specified seconds:

```
import (
    "github.com/jasonlvhit/gocron"
)

// ScheduleCron schedules job running at specified JobInterval
func (cron CronJob) ScheduleCron() {
    gocron.Every(uint64(120)).Second().Do(cron.run)
    <-gocron.Start()
}

func (cron CronJob) run() {
    fmt.Println("Cron Scheduled")
    cron.job.Run()
}
```

This runs the job every 2 minutes. However, I want the job to only run if the previous job has finished. In other words, only 1 job should be running at a time and preferably the next scheduled job should run 2 minutes after the previous job was completed. Is there any way to do that?

The library defines MAXJOBNUM const with value 10000, would it be right to set it to 1?

Comment: try change your code function `Second()` to `Seconds()`

Comment: well, I think you will need to use Mutex. https://gobyexample.com/mutexes

Comment: "The next scheduled job should run 2 minutes after the previous job was completed". That's not how cron works, though. Sounds like you just want a simple loop with a time.Sleep call: `for { cron.run(); time.Sleep(2*time.Minute) }`.

Comment: Come and use the active gocron -> https://github.com/go-co-op/gocron and Singleton mode as called out by the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit old question.Still thought of answering since I came across.
The SingletonMode() can be set for the purpose. As the comment says, the SingletonMode prevents a new job from starting if the prior job has not yet
completed it's run